# Not a normal subgroup by left and right coset

Tags: group-theory

If $G = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} a,b\in (\mathbb{R}) : a \neq 0$)

and assume G is a group under matrix multpication

Assume that K = ($\begin{pmatrix} s & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: s\in\mathbb{R}, s \neq 0$) is a subgroup of G. Prove that K is not a normal subgroup of G.

I want to prove this by showing the left cosets and the right cosets are not the same.

So if we take $g=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
 then $gK=\begin{pmatrix} as& b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

And if we take, $g'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
then $Kg'=\begin{pmatrix} sa' & sb' \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

How do i show that $gK \neq Kg'$, Is it sufficient to say that $Kg'$ has two columns that depend on s where as $gk$ only has one column that depend on S. So they are not equal

Comment: @JackBauer:  I'd be interested in how you picked this version, which has an upvoted Answer, to close as a duplicate of the linked version (whose only Answer is shorter and has no upvotes).

Answer (score 2):

Let $g=$ 
$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ with $b\ne 0$

Then  $g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{a} & -\frac{b}{a} \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

For $k=\begin{pmatrix}
    s & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ we get $gkg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    s & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{a} & -\frac{b}{a} \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
                       as & b \\
                       0&1\\
                       \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{a} & -\frac{b}{a} \\
    0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
                       s & -sb+b \\
                       0&1\\
                       \end{pmatrix}\notin K$

Comment: how does that show left coset does not equal right coset?

Comment: It proves that $K$ is not a normal subgroup. From that you know that the set of left cosets is not equal to the set of right cosets.